# Absolute addressing for runtime code replacement in x86_64

Tags: gcc, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, addressing

I'm currently using some code replace scheme in 32 bit where the code which is moved to another position, reads variables and a class pointer. Since x86_64 does not support absolute addressing I have trouble getting the correct addresses for the variables at the new position  of the code. The problem in detail is, that because of rip relative addressing the instruction pointer address is different than at compile time.

So is there a way to use absolute addressing in x86_64 or another way to get addresses of variables not instruction pointer relative?

Something like: `leaq variable(%%rax), %%rbx` would also help. I only want to have no dependency on the instruction pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the *large* code model for x86_64. In gcc this can be selected with *-mcmodel=large*. The compiler will use 64 bit absolute addressing for both code and data.

You could also add *-fno-pic* to disallow the generation of position independent code.

Edit: I built a small test app with *-mcmodel=large* and the resulting binary contains sequences like

```
400b81:       48 b9 f0 30 60 00 00    movabs $0x6030f0,%rcx
400b88:       00 00 00 
400b8b:       49 b9 d0 09 40 00 00    movabs $0x4009d0,%r9
400b92:       00 00 00 
400b95:       48 8b 39                mov    (%rcx),%rdi
400b98:       41 ff d1                callq  *%r9
```

which is a load of an absolute 64 bit immediate (in this case an address) followed by an indirect call or an indirect load. The instruction sequence

```
moveabs $variable, %rbx
addq %rax, %rbx
```

is the equivalent to a "leaq offset64bit(%rax), %rbx" (which doesn't exist), with some side effects like flag changing etc.

Comment: the -mcmodel=large should be the solution. i have to investigate why the gcc osx compiler doesn't support it

Comment: Maybe it's to old. The small (standard) and medium code models were added early, the large model came later.

Comment: i thank you so much this looks very good and definitly solves the absolut addressing problem

Comment: `movabs variable, %rbx` would be a load (and isn't encodeable with a 64-bit absolute address because the destination isn't RAX); did you mean `movabs $variable, %rbx` for `mov $imm64, %r64` (works for any register, unlike [the `moffs` loads that only work for AL/AX/EAX/RAX](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html))?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I missed the "$". Nice find.

Comment: `-fno-pic` doesn't *disallow* RIP-relative addressing modes, it simply turns off `-fPIC` / `-fpic`.  i.e. it disables the assumption of shared-library symbol-interposition, and it *allows* non-PIC absolute addressing, for addressing modes like `mov table(,%rcx,4), %eax` which embed a 32-bit absolute address.    See https://godbolt.org/g/XzFBrB for mcmodel=large vs. PIC vs. the default no-PIC.  Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) (`-fPIE` is enabled by default in many distros)

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is doable, but not very easy.

One way to do it is compensate for the code move in its instructions. You need to find all the instructions that use the RIP-relative addressing (they have the `ModRM` byte of 05h, 0dh, 15h, 1dh, 25h, 2dh, 35h or 3dh) and adjust their `disp32` field by the amount of move (the move is therefore limited to +/- 2GB in the virtual address space, which may not be guaranteed given the 64-bit address space is bigger than 4GB).

You can also replace those instructions with their equivalents, most likely replacing every original instruction with more than one, for example:

```
; These replace the original instruction and occupy exactly as many bytes as the original instruction:
  JMP Equivalent1
  NOP
  NOP
Equivalent1End:

; This is the code equivalent to the original instruction:
Equivalent1:
  Equivalent subinstruction 1
  Equivalent subinstruction 2
  ...
  JMP Equivalent1End
```

Both methods will require at least some rudimentary x86 disassembly routines.

The former may require the use of `VirtualAlloc()` on Windows (or some equivalent on Linux) to ensure the memory that contains the patched copy of the original code is within +/- 2GB of that original code. And allocation at specific addresses can still fail.

The latter will require more than just primitive disassemblying, but also full instruction decoding and generation.

There may be other quirks to work around.

Instruction boundaries may also be found by setting the `TF` flag in the `RFLAGS` register to make the CPU generate the `single-step` debug interrupt at the end of execution of every instruction. A debug exception handler will need to catch those and record the value of RIP of the next instruction. I believe this can be done using `Structured Exception Handling (SEH)` in Windows (never tried with the debug interrupts), not sure about Linux. For this to work you'll have to make all of the code execute, every instruction.

Btw, there's absolute addressing in 64-bit mode, see, for example the MOV to/from accumulator instructions with opcodes from 0A0h through 0A3h.

Comment: thanks for the answer. as far as i understand you, the approach is to recalculate the address value for the movs at runtime. This looks to heavy for the scheme so if that is the only way i would think about a different implementation